# Disable Redmine Activity Tab for anonymous users

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

In Redmine you can set permissions for anonymous users (users without a login) under:

> Administration / Roles and permissions / Anonymous

But there is no way to disable the Activity Tab in the available configs.

I'm looking for a way to hide this tab, while showing others like issues, repo, etc. Another limitation is that it should only be hidden from anonymous users, but not completely removed from the system.

Comment: I believe this link should help you out: https://redmine.org/issues/1543